# can't understand where is syntax error

Tags: c

This is a code for checking a string is palindrome or not (in C language). But it contains a syntax error. In the second `for` loop it says

> Expected ")" before ;

---

***Image :***

### [image].

***Code :***

```
int i,j,c=0,flag=0;
char input[3];
printf("Enter a string\n");
scanf("%s",&input);
for(i=0;input[i]!='\0';i++) {
    c++;
}
for(i=0;j=c-1;i<=j;j>=0;i++;j--) {   // error shows in this line
    if(input[i]==input[j]){
        flag=1;
        break;
    }
}
if(flag==1){
    puts("character is a palindrome");
}
else
{
    puts("character is not a palindrome");
}
```

Comment: yes; please; do ; read ; the ; syntax.

Comment: ... for the `for (;;)` expression.

Comment: Don't post images of text/code! You are required to post it as text **in the question itself**!

Comment: the posted code is missing: 1) the `#include` statments, 2) any declaration of a function, and is very difficult to read due to lack of consistent indention, multiple variable declarations per line, lack of separation between code blocks, and other problems.

Comment: the call to `scanf()` has a number of problems: 1) the returned value is not being checked to assure the operation was successful.  2) missing a 'max length' modifier on the '%s' input/conversion specifier, which means the user can easily overflow the input buffer, resulting in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.  3) in C, a reference to an array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array, so no '&' is needed.

Comment: there is a logic error, this expression: `;j=c-1` can result in 'j' being negative.  The second `for()` loop exits if any char matches, it should always check all the characters, and set a 'not palindrome' indication of any mismatch is found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) `scanf("%s",input)` and not `scanf("%s",&input)`

`input` holds the address of the array. `&input` passes the address of `input`.

2) Syntax of `for` loop is:

```
for ( init; condition; increment ) {
  //code
 }
```

Hence the `for` loop should be:

```
for(i=0,j=c-1;i<=j && j>=0;i++,j--)
```

Comment: The semantics are very different. Commas are not just some other kind of seperators.

Comment: @Olaf, I will make the correction.

Comment: Thanks, this will help me a lot

Comment: @MIM, I see that you unaccepted my answer, was any improvement necessary?

Comment: No both of your answers are right.

Comment: @MIM, oh.. you can accept only one answer but you can upvote all the answers that helped you. This should provide more information - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

this statement:

```
for(i=0;j=c-1;i<=j;j>=0;i++;j--) {
```

has 6 sections, but a `for()` statement is only allowed 3 section.

Suggest:

```
for(i=0, j=c-1; i<=j, j>=0; i++, j--) {
```

Notice the correct use of commas to separate expressions in the three parts of the statement.

There are other problems with the code, but the above will go along ways toward getting the posted code to compile